# How to start and bind to a service?

Tags: java, android, service

I think and hope that this is not the old usual question.
This is what I want:

1. An Activity A that starts a service S with setForeground() set (that is a service with the persistent notification);
2. A to bind to S to control it with a public method;
3. the user closes A (onDestroy) but the service must still running;
4. the user opens A, A finds the service S already started and simply it rebind to it.

How can I do that?

Comment: Did you read the documentation? http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I do that?

Step #4 is identical to Step #1 and Step #2, so you just do the same thing in both cases: call both `startService()` and `bindService()`. In your case, do your `startForeground()` work in `onCreate()` of the service (not `onStartCommand()`), as you do not need that to be done multiple times (one per `startService()` call). And be sure to have a clear plan on when you will stop that service via `stopService()` or `stopSelf()` — [only have the service running when it is actively delivering value to the user](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/07/27/role-services.html).

Comment: Yes, my fault. I deleted my comment to avoid you to read that (because now I have solved), but you have already answered. Anyways I was wrong to believe that the method onBind() was called again. Now it works, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you call startService, while the service is already running, nothing will happen. Services are automatically created as singletons, so the framework will take care of only having 1 instance up.

In the onCreate() of your service, call `startForeground(int id, Notification notif)`.

As you've set it as startForeground, destroying the Activity that's bound to the service will not destroy it, so no issues there.

Now simply bind to the service in your onResume of your activity, and unbind in onPause or onStop (whatever fits you best, both can be used in different setups).